# Passing WebSocket parameters to a programmatical endpoint

Tags: java, websocket

My front-end code looks like this:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost/yeah?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

My endpoint at the backend is programmatical:

```
class YeahEndpoint extends Endpoint {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig ec) {
        Map<String, String> params = session.getPathParameters(); <-- returns empty map! No param1 or param2.
    }
    ...
}
```

As I was not able to find relevant information on the web, I need to ask this here: how a programmatical endpoint obtains the request parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply should have used `session.getQueryString()` instead of `session.getPathParameters()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Jetty as the back-end, look at the following code:

```
session.getUpgradeRequest().getParameter("param")
```